# getCameraIntrinsics by rotation display or not

Tags: google-project-tango, tango, c-api

So Tango C API offers its main way of getting the [TangoCameraIntrinsics struct](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/c/reference/struct/tango-camera-intrinsics#struct_tango_camera_intrinsics) using the `TangoService_getCameraIntrinsics` [function call](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/c/reference/group/camera#group___camera_1ga61f047f290983da9d16522371977cecf) but its support library also offers the `TangoSupport_getCameraIntrinsicsBasedOnDisplayRotation` [function call](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/c/support/reference/group/misc-utilities#tangosupport_getcameraintrinsicsbasedondisplayrotation)

I have looked and can't really understand what the use of passing the display rotation does different.

> This function will query the camera intrinsics and rotate them
>   according to the display rotation.

Won't it return the camera intrinsics based on the rotation by default anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, the camera intrinsics are fixed per device, so the first function will not change based on rotation, no.

The rotation version is useful for making a 3D camera that has the same FOV and projection matrix as the color camera.